# jQuery get the class name that was attached with

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery plugin and I am having trouble adding a click listener

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.rockon = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $(document).on('click', '.rockon', function () {

            });
       });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I initialize the plugin as

```
$(".rockon").rockon();
```

However, instead of listening to ".rockon" for a click, how can I listen to the element that I attached the plugin to.

I would normally do

```
$this.attr("class");
```

however the element has multiple classes

Comment: Are you creating a plugin just to add a click handler?

Comment: No lol, I didn't bother adding the entire source as it would be pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gh4w2te/)**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.rockon = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $(document).on('click', this, function () {

            });
       });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

this will listen for the click event on the selected element!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
        $.fn.rockon = function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.on('click', function () {
                    console.log("click");
                });
            });
        };
```